# about xpath when using scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

xpath sentences:

```
item['title'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first()
item['content'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]').extract_first()
```

results：

```
{
'title': '\t史蒂芬霍金',
'content': '<div class="content"><div>能够在过去这么多年的时间里研究并学习宇宙学<br>\r\n对我来说意义非凡</div></div>'
}
```

**questions：**

1、How to remove `\t` in `title` field?
2、How to remove `<div class="content"></div>` in `content` field?(the children nodes can not be removed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `strip()` for title:

```
item['title'] = response.xpath(
                    '//span[@class="title"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
```

And you can chain your selector with XPath's `string()` or `normalize-space()` for content:

```
item['content'] = response.xpath(
                      '//div[@class="content"]').xpath('string(.)').extract_first()
```

Comment: thanks.`title` filed is ok now.For `content`, I want to retain inner `div` and other labels,only outer <div class="content"></div> don't be needed. I use `normalize-space()` or `string(.)`,all the inner labels disapear.

Comment: Then you can try `"".join(response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]/node()').extract())`

Answer (score 1):

```
item['content'] = response.xpath('string(//div[@class="content"])').extract_first()
```

`string()` will concatenate all the text in the current node.

if you want to get rid of white space, you can use `normalize-space()`, it's like python's `strip()` that built on top of `string()`:

```
item['content'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="content"])').extract_first()
```